# iOS9 UIWebView blank screen

Tags: ios, webview, uiwebview, xamarin, ios9

I've been experiencing weird behaviour on iOS9 when trying to load in-app HTML pages into our UIWebView - sometimes the pages load, sometimes just appearing as a blank screen.

The webViewDidFinishLoad function gets called in these instances as well (but no didFailLoadWithError). I can't seem to find any clues as to what would be making the page not visible *some* of the time. A lot of the other questions I found here suggest issues with the path, but I would think it'd be consistantly failing if that was the case.

The same code works fine on iOS 8.

Comment: Did you try to debug it with Safari?

Comment: Debugging in Safari shows the HTML is loaded, yet the screen is still blank. When I ask Safari to reload the page, it then appears on the device screen, visible this time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

add into info.plist file

> NSAppTransportSecurity 
>   
>       NSAllowsArbitraryLoads

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a go.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem, however you should consider setting the it up properly for any domains where you want to ensure security is correct level.

Answer (score 2):

As @vmthiru said, you need to add that to the Info.plist file. Although the exact format would be:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
  </dict>
```

Meaning that if you do it via the XCode UI, you would need to add the NSAppTransportSecurity key (with Dictionary type), and inside of it, add a boolean with key NSAppTransportSecurity and set it to YES.

That said, you will probably notice that there are some viewport bugs in iOS 9 still, but that has nothing to do with this.

Hope it helps